# Magento 2 Customer Listing action: get customer's telephone

Tags: magento2, customer-address, customer-grid

I have a module where I have added an additional action on admin panel, under Customers -> All Customers grid. I show the new action by populating file: `view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="mynewaction">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">mynewaction</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Execute a custom action</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="modulename/customfolder/customAction"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Execute a custom action</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom question to confirm my custom action?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

The implementation of the custom mass action is on `Controller/Adminhtml/Customfolder/CustomAction.php`

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Customfolder;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;

class CustomAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $filter;
    protected $customerCollectionFactory;
    protected $_helper;

    public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, 
            \MyModule\Helper\Data $helper, 
            \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->customerCollectionFactory = $customerCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->customerCollectionFactory->create());
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $sms = $item->getEmail();
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    }
}
```

Instead of `getEmail()` I need to get the customer's phone (if any). However function `getTelephone()` doesn't seem to work. How can I access customer's phone?

Keep in mind that the customer is not associated with any order, so I can't get the phone from the order object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The telephone number is related to the customer's addresses and not to the customer's account. So a solution will be to get the customer's default billing or shipping and get the telephone number using the customerRepository `Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface`  and the addressRepository `Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface` like

```
 $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
 $billingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
 $shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();

//get default billing address
 try {
    $billingAddress = $this->addressRepository->getById($billingAddressId);
    $telephone = $billingAddress->getTelephone();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //
}
```